# Update definition of SCEP on windows servers using powershell

Tags: powershell

i am trying to update the definition of SCEP on remote Windows Servers using MpCmdRun.exe which exists under "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\platform\*\MpCmdRun.exe. Unfortunately it is not accepting -filepath. says its null or empty. below is my code

```
$comp = "SRV1234"
$MpCmdRun = invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {get-item -Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\platform\\*\MpCmdRun.exe" | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullname -First 1}
     
invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath $MpCmdRun -ArgumentList "-signatureUpdate" -Wait}
```

Below is the error:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FilePath'. The argument is null
> or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try
> the command again.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingValidationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: Did you test to see what path was returned in `$MpCmdRun` ?

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> $mpcmdrun
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\platform\4.18.2201.10-0\MpCmdRun.exe 

PS C:\Windows\system32> $MpCmdRun.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                              
True     True     String                                   System.Object

Comment: Try `-FilePath $using:MpCmdRun`